# date() only year from date format YYYY-00-00

Tags: php, date

I try to do this `echo date("Y", strtotime("1999-00-00"));` but instead of `1999` it returns `1998`. Is there a way how to handle this? I would prefer a "clean way", not something like `$finalYear = (float)$year+1` etc.
The date format MUST be `YYYY-00-00` (with zeros)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're absolutely sure that the date's format will never change, you'd be better off with

```
echo substr('1999-00-00', 0, 4);
```

rather than incurring the heavy overhead of strtotime() and roundtripping through the entire date/time subsystem.

When you tell PHP's date functions that the month/day are 0, which are "invalid", it'll convert those to the appropriate "previous" values.

e.g.

```
1999-00-10 is actually 1998-12-10
1999-11-00 is actually 1999-10-31
```

and so on. It's like saying "yesterday" or "last month". similarly, specifying month 13 makes it

```
1999-13-01 is actually 2000-01-01
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be because `00` is not a valid month. The earliest month would be `01`. Same with day.

```
echo date('Y', strtotime('1999-01-01'));
```

Perhaps changes should be made wherever you retrieve the date you're trying to parse?

Answer (score 1):

As the first legit day of the year is YYYY-01-01, I think the 'unclean' way you cited is perfectly reasonable here.

Or, perhaps, it's even better just to extract the first four digits with the substr(), if the argument of strtotime() is what you've got from the user input.

Answer (score -2):

The only way to get 1999 is with

```
echo date( "Y", strtotime( "1999" ) );
```

Comment: This is the same as just `echo '1999';` so the use of the two functions seems useless doesn't it? I think the whole point is that OP's dates are already formatted as `YYYY-00-00`.

Comment: Surely this is not a clean way but this is my second trying: `echo date_create( "1999-00-00" )->add( new DateInterval( "P1M2D" ) )->format("Y");`